# Ошибка при подключении DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

У меня есть DLL библиотека. Вот ее код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__declspec(dllexport) void dummy()
{
    cout << "I am program";
}


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        cout << "hello,world!\n";
    }
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        cout << "good-bye,world!\n";
    }
}
```

Также есть обычный exe файл, который пишет

> Hello, World!

. Я заставил его подключать dll с помощью **hiew32** (изменил секцию import).
Но когда я запускаю exe вылезает эта ошибка:

> Точка входа в процедуру dummy не найдена в библиотеке DLL
> C:\Users\user\source\repos\project\release\HelloWorld.exe

Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Во время связывания ищется имя `dummy`, но не находит, потому что оно у вас декорировано в стиле С++. Уберите декорирование добавлением `extern "C"`

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void dummy()
```

UPD: еще стоит убедиться, что у вас стоит правильное соглашение о вызове. По умолчанию это `__cdecl`.

Подробнее о декорировании имен вы можете почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2017), или можно просто набрать в гугле "name mangling".